What do you think about all existence following the very same laws?
So, i was wondering: Planets, Stars, etc. Have a similar behavior to us, humans. I mean, they consume energy to stay "alive" and when this energy ends up they "die". And in the end we’re all the same "cosmic dust" from the beginning, that has become: Oxygen, Carbon, Hydrogen, etc.
But what if the similarities don’t stop there? What if these other corpses have the same archaic laws of the living beings? What if they follow the law of preservation of the "species", the sun burns to "stay alive", what if the black holes are a method of the universe to preserve its own existence, to somehow "transport" all the matter of our universe to another place?
Do you agree with that? Use the law of the living to explain reality itself. If so, the "beginning" of existence should have something similar with a birth, a birth like any other existing being.

Well at some level every thing does follow the same laws - the laws of physics. Is that a valid answer to your question?

This is my mysticism than philosophy.

I don't see any extra explanatory power being added by assuming objects like black holes, stars, or the universe have purposes.
The sun continues in its current state because it burns. What would it add to say that "it burns to stay alive"?
But regardless, one cannot draw from the observation that things in the universe can be talked about as if they were alive the conclusion that the universe had a beginning.

What I meant is how beings unwittingly allow themselves to continue to exist, whether in cells that do cell division or in stars that burn and generate light and heat. Why do bodies exist and why do they continue to exist? Why doesn’t my body let me stay awake? Why does it care if I sleep? To regain energy, why does he want to regain energy? Why does he have to keep acting in such a way as to keep me alive? Aren’t celestial bodies the same way?
(I think that’s what I meant to say this morning...)


Use the law of the living to explain reality itself

This is a strong statement.
Although intuitively, we can find some truth in it.
I would take the most fundamental law of theoretical physics: "The conservation of information".

"This law says that at the most basic level the time evolution of
physical systems preserves information"

That would imply that the elements of the periodic table produced in the first generation of stars were necessary to create life. So, life alone, could be the reason for the universe's existence:

"following the very same laws?"

